# Lightweight in-memory noSQL database for the browser?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

Is there a lightweight in-memory database for use in the browser? Preferably something actively maintained and with a similar API to mongodb

Comment: [Most browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb) (including IE10!) have a native support for an integrated database called [IndexedBD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)

Comment: My understanding of IndexedDB is that it's a persistent store, is that wrong?

Comment: ah, so you want something that disappears on page refresh? You explicitely want a non-persistent DB? In that case, I don't know

Comment: I probably used improper terminology there - basically yes. A non persistent datastore that isn't shared between tabs or sessions

Answer (score 2):

While this question isn't appropriate for StackOverflow (see: [What exactly is a recommendation question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question))

You can look into something like [SQL.js](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/) -- it uses an API similar to SQLite (because it is SQLite) rather than MongoDB. I've personally worked with it, and it works - don't expect much more than "yeah, it's a database"

I haven't tried it, but [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) might be closer to what you're looking for. Its syntax looks a little closer to MongoDB.

In the future, software recommendations belong on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/